# How to write a wrapper function in R?

Tags: r, function, wrapper

I am writing a wrapper function. I am moving text at the command line to a variety of columns and would like to make some 'shortcut' functions with predefined defaults to assist.  I have made a small data frame and function to illustrate my issue.

```
myDF = data.frame(quotes = c("dont panic", "time is an illusion", "space is big"), 
go_here = character(3), go_there = character(3), stringsAsFactors = F)
```

The function 'moveTo' is given the word I want to move (term2move) and the column I would like to move it to (placement_column).

```
library(stringr)

moveTo = function(term2move, placement_column, funcDF = myDF)
{
    funcDF[,placement_column] = str_extract(funcDF$quotes, term2move)
    assign("myDF", funcDF, envir = .GlobalEnv)
}
```

To show with an example,

```
moveTo("dont", "go_here")
```

places the word 'dont' in the column myDF$go_here.

I am looking to find out how to make a function like 'moveToGo_Here' that will only require the term2move as an argument and automatically place it in myDF$go_here. I'd then write a similar function for moveToGo_There.

I was hoping the following function and call would work, but it doesn't.

```
moveToGo_Here = function(term2move)
{
    placement_column = "go_here"
    moveTo()
}

moveToGo_Here("illusion")
```

Comment: Use `moveTo(term2move, "go_here")` inside `moveToGo_Here`.

Comment: Super thanks @Stibu. I was closer than I thought. I had read somewhere not to put the args in the internal function - I must have been way of course on that. I'm off to build in my real life data.